# C++ stod function equivalent

Tags: c++

A friend of mine sent me his program. He uses **"stod"** function to convert string to double. Is there any other possibility to do such thing?

My complier shows error "stod was not declared in this scope"

I've included `#include <string> #include <cstdlib>` but nothing has changed.

My complier doesn't use C++11 features. By the way, that program were prepared as a school project, without purpose of using C++11.

Comment: Use `stringstream` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Comment: Note that you really need `std::stod()`; your friend may have a `using namespace std;` somewhere.

Comment: @Keith std::stod is from C++11

Comment: @Steephen; hence a comment not an answer; it may still be helpful to the OP.

Comment: Get yourself a modern compiler, and don't waste time learning how we struggled with C++ in past decades unless you have an interest in history.

Comment: @Keith: If it's used on strings, ADL should kick in.

Answer (score 5):

`std::atof()` is a quick option handed over from C language, you have to include `<cstdlib>` to use it.

Otherwise  you can use std::stringstream to handle it.

```
    #include<sstream> 

    std::string value="14.5";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<< value;

    double d=0.0;
    ss>>d;
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to convert a string to a double would be

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string text;
double value;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << text;
ss >> value;
```

But be aware of the error check needed to validate correct conversion

EDIT: You will need to test the stringstream for failure with

```
if (ss.fail()) { /* error */ }
```

Source http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: You can alternatively use `std::istreamstream ss(text)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried to supply a simple example with separated steps